# jQuery-ui widegets in 3D-like recessed panel

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Related to the [question]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306815/jquery-ui-accordian-wont-do-its-thing on the jQuery-UI, I don't see Panels as part of the library. I'm sure there are many out there but my question may be a simple CSS one ( I stink at CSS). I need to display the jQuery-UI widgets in a 3d-like or I should just say "panel" with a thick border and recessed area in which the control is displayed. Can someone show me the relevant CSS or else a Panel widget?

I found my own answer:
Create a div with the properties:

```
#members 
{
float: left;
width: 400px;
border-width: 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #cccccc;
}
```